# Concatenate string in .csv after x commas using shell/bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have several .csv files containing data. The data vendor created the files indicating the years **once** in the first line with missing values in between, variables names in the second. Data follows in the third to the Xth line.

```
"year 1", , , "year 2", , ,"year 2", , ,
"Var1", "Var2", "Var3", "Var1", "Var2", "Var3", "Var1", "Var2", "Var3"
"ABC" , 1234  , 4567  , "DEF"  , 789   , "ABC" , 1234  , 4567  , "DEF"
```

I am new to shell programming but it shouldn't be too complicated writing a script that outputs the following

```
"Var1_year1", "Var2_year1", "Var3_year1", "Var1_year2", "Var2_year2", "Var3_year2", "Var1_year3", "Var2_year3", "Var3_year3"
"ABC" , 1234  , 4567  , "DEF"  , 789   , "ABC" , 1234  , 4567  , "DEF"
```

Some thing like

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/Users/pathTo.csvfiles/*.csv
for f in $FILES
do
  echo "Processing $f file..."
  # 1. Replace the second line with 'Varname_YearX' where YearX comes from the first line
  cat ????
  # 2. Delete first line
  sed -i '' 1d $f
done

echo "Processing complete."
```

Update: The .csv files vary in their amount of lines. Only the first two lines need to be edited, the following lines are data.

Comment: Please specify whether the input files have only **two** lines each, or whether they might be composed of an *even* number of lines of the described two-line format.

Comment: The files vary in their amount of lines. However, only the first two lines contain information we want to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to merge the first and the second line of each CSV, try this.

```
# No point in using a variable for the wildcard
for f in /Users/pathTo.csvfiles/*.csv
do
    awk -F , 'NR==1 { # Collect first line
            # Squash quotes
            gsub(/"/, "")
            for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)
                y[i] = $i || y[i-1]
            next  # Do not fall through to print
            }
        NR==2 { # Combine collected with current
            gsub(/"/, "")
            for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)
                $i = y[i] "_" $i
        }
        # Print everything (except first)
        1' "$f" > "$f.tmp"
        mv "$f.tmp" "$f"
done
```

The first loop simply copies the previous field's value to `y[i]` if the `i`:th field is empty.

Comment: I removed the chitchat prints. Probably also remove the directory and simply do `for f in *.csv` to be able to run this on all CSV files in the current directory, in any directory you like.

Comment: adding an if-else statement in the first loop `if($i != "") y[i] = $i  else y[i] = y[i-1]` and editing the second loop to read `$i =  $i "_" y[i] ","` make it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ugly code using [`csvtool`](http://forge.ocamlcore.org/projects/csv/), various standard tools, and `bash`:

```
i=file.csv
paste -d_ <(head -2 $i | tail -1 | csvtool transpose -) \
          <(head -1 $i |           csvtool transpose -  | 
                            sed '$d;s/ //;/^$/{g;b};h') | 
csvtool transpose - | sed 's/[^,]*/"&"/g' | cat - <(tail +3 $i)
```

Output:

```
"Var1_year1","Var2_year1","Var3_year1","Var1_year2","Var2_year2","Var3_year2","Var1_year2","Var2_year2","Var3_year2"
"ABC" , 1234  , 4567  , "DEF"  , 789   , "ABC" , 1234  , 4567  , "DEF"
```